# How can I send an email with no Intent, and with a photo with an attachment?

Tags: java, android-studio, email

I'm trying to make an application that sends an email taking the fields by some edit text; Then it has to shoot a photo and send the email with the subject, the text and the photo previously mentioned.
I started creating two buttons, one for the camera, and one for the email.
I will probably use one for everything.
That' only a try, but I haven't found anything on the internet in how to link an attachment in JavaMail.

Can u please help me? I'm really struggling for a solution.

That's the Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText mEmail;
    public EditText mSubject;
    public EditText mMessage;
    public Button mSend;
    public Button takePicture;
    protected static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 0;
    Bitmap thumbnail;
    File pic;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mailID);
        mMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageID);
        mSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subjectID);
        mSend = findViewById(R.id.send);
        takePicture = findViewById(R.id.takePicture);
        mSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMail();
            }
        });
        takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMail() {
        String mail = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String message = mMessage.getText().toString();
        String subject = mSubject.getText().toString().trim();

        JavaMailAPI javaMailAPI = new JavaMailAPI(this, mail, subject, message);

        javaMailAPI.execute();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);


            try {
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                if (root.canWrite()) {
                    pic = new File(root, "pic.png");
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pic);
                    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("BROKEN", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

That's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mailID"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/subjectID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Subject"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/messageID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Message"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takePicture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take Picture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use Intent?

Comment: Bc my intention is to not use other email application